# json serialize Lists with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I would like to use newtonsoft json serialzer to create json.
I'm totaly new in building LIST and collections, so I will ask you for help.
To create a simple json will work.
I have to build a attribute list, with a attributelist.

Maybee there is an other libary, making this easier ?

I need this json:

```
{
    "objectTypeId": 545,
    "attributes": [{
        "objectTypeAttributeId": 222,
        "objectAttributeValues": [{
            "value": "Kommentar"
        }]
    }]
}
```

So for this I startet to

```
public class Controller
{
        public int objectTypeId { get; set; }
        public IList<string> attributes { get; set; }
}

Controller controllerjson = new Controller
{
  objectTypeId = 545,
  // How to add the attributes with each values ?
}
```

Comment: [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your c# class model can't match with your JSON data.

There are two way can create model easily.

1. You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
2. If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead of use http://json2csharp.com/ online JSON to Model class.

You can try to use those models to carry your JSON Format.

```
public class ObjectAttributeValue
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int objectTypeAttributeId { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectAttributeValue> objectAttributeValues { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int objectTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

You can use like this.

```
RootObject controllerjson = new RootObject()
{
    objectTypeId = 545,
    attributes = new List<Attribute>() {
        new Attribute() {
            objectTypeAttributeId = 222,
            objectAttributeValues = new List<ObjectAttributeValue>() {
                new ObjectAttributeValue() { value= "Kommentar" }
            }
        }
    }
};

string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(controllerjson);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyOHFb)